# how to get current user in spring security integrated with cas?

Tags: spring-security, cas

I have integrated CAS to Spring Security using Spring security tutorial on cas wiki. Now I want to get the current user and don't know how!

Should I get it from Spring security or CAS?

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns null :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! I was going to use my own Access Control system, so I commented filters who where responsible for checking user's roles to access URLs. Apparently if I don't intercept URLs, spring security's context won't be accessible through that request (or at least it seems like that! I am not a big fan of Documents, so I try out codes and when I get an exception, I try to guess the reason! I really should stop doing that :| but anyway now that I intercept URLs, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() doesn't return null anymore :) )

Comment: I'm facing this problem too. Could you please elaborate your solution?

Comment: The problem in my case was that I had commented lines in spring security config to intercept URLs. There is an interceptor which checks if user is authenticated. search for something like that!

Answer (score 0):

If SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is null means that the user is not authenticated yet.

Some pointers on CAS

1. Make sure that you use SSL for the communication to CAS thus CAS
   must be hosted on SSL ports (443 or 8443)
2. Make sure that you Spring
   Apps is hosted on SSL ports so that CAS can call to your Spring via
   SSL server.

Common error is that both CAS and Spring Apps are not on SSL ports.
If this is the case, get a free SSL cert from www.startssl.com

Comment: I know! there is no problem in logging in and SSO. both applications are in https...

Comment: In that case, make sure that SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is called in a controller whose URL is protected by Spring Security i.e. you cannot access the page without logging in.

Comment: There is no problem with that too! When I try to load a URL, it redirects me to CAS(https), and after logging in I can't get the current user...